# Sending checkbox form array to email, formatting

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

I have three php pages. First is a selection.php page with options selected by checkboxes. On submit, the options are displayed and an email field (optional) to send the results to. The problem is in the email message's format. See below for code, email results, and ideal output. I appreciate anyone's help and time!

selection.php

```
    $sqlSAT1 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 1'";
    $sqlSAT2 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 2'";  
    $sqlSAT3 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 3'"; 

    mysql_query($sqlSAT1); 
    $result = mysql_query($sqlSAT1);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<ul><li>";
    echo'<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].' " id="bandSched_' . $row['id'] . '" />';
    echo '<label for="bandSched_' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['timeShow']." ".$row['bandName'] . '</label>'; 
    echo "</li></ul>";

    }


    ?>
```

results.php

```
       <?php
      if ( ! empty($_POST['id']))
    { foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) { $_POST['id'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$key]); } 
    $in = implode(', ', $_POST['id']); 

    $sqlSAT1 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 1' AND id IN ($in) ORDER BY FIELD(id, $in)"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sqlSAT1) or die('MySQL Error ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error()); 
    }
    if ( ! isset($result))
    {
    echo 'You did not select anything';
    }
    else
    {
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['timeShow'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bandName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    }

    ?>
```

and EmailProcess.php

```
        <?php
    $to = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "This is subject";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $headers .= "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(!(!isset($value))){$set=1;}
    if(is_array($value)){
    $message = $message . "$key: ".implode( ', ', $value)."\n\n";
    } else {
    $message = $message . "$key: $value\n\n";
    }
    }
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if( $retval == true )  
    {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
    }?>
```

Finally, this is what the actual email with results looks like-

```
    divcontent:

    <div class=\"saturdaySched full_width light_gray\">
    <div style=\"padding:20px\">

    <h2>SATURDAY</h2>

    <div id=\"stage1sat\" class=\"stageBox\">
    <h3>STAGE 1</h3>
    <table>
    <tbody><tr><td>11:30</td><td>G.Wizz</td></tr><tr><td>12:20</td><td>Sideshow Tramps</td></tr><tr><td>1:40</td><td>Clap Your Hands
    Say Yeah</td></tr>        </tbody></table>
    </div>



    <div id=\"stage2sat\" class=\"stageBox\">

    <h3>STAGE 2</h3>
    <table>

    <tbody><tr><td>12:00</td><td>The Wheel Workers</td></tr><tr><td>2:20</td><td>Starfucker</td></tr><tr><td>3:40</td><td>Phantogram</td></tr>
```

Ideal email format could be as simple as a list (or something similar)

```
Stage 1- band1 2:30
Stage 1- band5 3:30
Stage 2- band4 3:10
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following headers while sending mail:

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

Comment: I added that (see code above) yet all of the /html/ is being displayed still.

Comment: It looks good- yet I'm getting this at the end of the email message:  email: jon@site.com x: 0 y: 0

Comment: It's up there under EmailProcess.php

Comment: One thing I noticed- idk if it's any clue- but some examples don't use the dot before the = in the $headers= I'm using them in all as you suggested and they work now. I'm going to try added .= to the other message $

Comment: try var_dump $_POST on EmailProcesss.php and let me know what u getting

Comment: trying var_dump- my .= additions just made everything repeat

Comment: $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $headers .= "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n"; i can see one problme in this for first time don't use $headers .= just use $header =

Comment: Can you tell me where to insert var_dump $_POST

Comment: try var_dump just above $to = $_POST["email"];

Comment: array(4) { ["results"]=> string(1847) "
SATURDAY
STAGE 1
4:20 Z-Ro
STAGE 2
1:00 Best Coast
SUNDAY
" ["email"]=> string(27) "me@myemailaddress.com" ["x"]=> string(1) "0" ["y"]=> string(1) "0" } Message sent successfully...

Comment: It's printing and sending the email address from the form field.

Comment: Hmmm I think I have to omit the 'email' key somehow

Comment: use unset($_POST['email']); before loop, and i think u would also like to remove 'x' and 'y' :)

Comment: trying this now- and I would like to remove x and y! How do I do that?

Comment: use unset($_POST['x']); and unset($_POST['y']);

Comment: Excellent- had to sleep for a while.

Comment: And the X:0 Y:0 is showing up because the submit button is an image- I  will try the unset options, but I just changed the submit to text and that killed the X:0 Y:0

Comment: One more thing- when I do var_dump I see the name of the array(2) { ["Selections"]=> string(2033) " and 'Selections is showing up in the email as well like Selections: Next line: Data. It doesn't look bad, but I like full control. Can I hide just the name (unsetting 'selections' removes from loop)?

Comment: Comments are not a place to have a rolling debug session, take it to chat.